# Unable to install synergy on red hat 5.4

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, libraries, glibc, glib

I'm trying to install [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/download/) on Red Hat Linux 5.4 but I'm getting the below errors:

```
rpm -ivh synergy-1.3.8-Linux-x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
    libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.11)(64bit) is needed by synergy-1.3.8-1.x86_64
    libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.14)(64bit) is needed by synergy-1.3.8-1.x86_64
    libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.9)(64bit) is needed by synergy-1.3.8-1.x86_64
```

I have a Red Hat CD with me which may contain these dependencies but I'm not sure how to install them. I do not have a license for Red Hat, so I cannot use Red Hat support.

I tried creating a repo file which points to /media DVD and tried to use `yum install synergy` directly but that didn't work either.

If the CD doesn't contain these dependencies, what other options are available for me?

Comment: Why are you using RHEL if you don't have a license? You do have other options.

Comment: I want to try out on Red Hat only since I've everything setup on my red hat & I don't want to switch to another OS for now.

Comment: Not having access to the repos will significantly cut down what you can try.

Comment: You can use the Fedora repositories.